# Desarrollo sistema de Turnos Sincronizacion

Tags: java, sync-framework, ingenieria-del-software

Buen día!
Hay algunos sistemas dando vuelta sobre Turnos o Appointments en ingles.
Mi consulta es mas del tema Infraestructura que Programación,al menos hoy.

Supongan que tienen un software en la nube que maneja turnos ,y hay algunos lugares (Por ejemplos clínicas) que lo usan.
Es decir,sus pacientes pueden entrar a una web,elegir esa clínica y reservar el turno.
**Hasta ahí,todo perfecto.**

Pero las clínicas,también tienen atención al teléfono,es decir,la persona que atiende,también debe guardar los turno,debería guardarlo en el sistema que esta corriendo en la nube tambien.

Ahora bien,que pasa si en el lugar físico de la clínica o establecimiento (Donde la persona toma los turnos por teléfono),hay un momento en el día que se corta Internet.
Se que igual se podría guardar la información y luego sincronizarla,eso es correcto,pero en el mientras tanto,el que saca turnos vía Web,esta desactualizado,tal vez ,elige un Turno que ya fue tomado por teléfono y aun como no hay conexión en el lugar,no se sincronizo.

Lo único que se me ocurre,es que la supuesta plataforma Web,apunte a una instalación local en el establecimiento,que chupe la información de ahí,a lo sumo,si en el establecimiento no hay Internet,no se va a poder conectar y la persona tendrá que llamar por teléfono,pero al menos no se genera ninguna incongruencia.**Igual es una solución que no me gusta.**

Se les ocurre otra manera de como resolver este rompecabezas?
Mil Gracias!

Comment: El telefonista dice "lo siento, el sistema se ha caido, vuelva a llamar en 15 minutos". Sin saber datos de lo frecuente y duraderos que se espera que sean los cortes no es fácil decidir cuál es la mejor opción; un corte de 2 minutos cada tres meses a medianoche no exige la misma solución que un corte de 10 minutos cada hora en horario laboral.

Comment: Si,estoy de acuerdo.Lo que pasa,que uno tiene que estar preparado para cualquier tipo de circustancia.
Podria ser un corte cada 3 meses como decis,pero que pasa si un dia por X razon,fallo todo el dia?
La clinica no puede dejar de tomar turnos.Mil gracias por tu opinion nasjan